# Cant align Typography under App Bar Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

I'm building a AppBar component,
and I need the menu button to be left aligned, and the text in the center, but I can't do it at all

already tried this solution [Align typography component to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248358/align-typography-component-to-the-right)

I've tried a lot of things, including, grids, padding(stupid solution) etc

And this just dont align

```
import React from 'react';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  link: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    color:"inherit",
    variant:"h8"
  },
  text:{

  },



}));

export default function CustomAppBar(logged) {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);



  function handleMenu(event) {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>

          <IconButton
                aria-label="Meny=u"
                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleMenu}
                color="inherit"
              >
                <AccountCircle />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                keepMounted
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
              >
                <MenuItem onClick={()=> {window.location = "/Carrier/Home"}}><Typography className={classes.link}>Balance</Typography></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={()=> {window.location = "/Document/Send"}}><Typography className={classes.link}>Send Document</Typography></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={()=> {window.location = "/Carrier/AddTravel"}}><Typography className={classes.link}>New Travel</Typography></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={()=> {window.location = "/Carrier/Balance"}}><Typography className={classes.link}>Balance</Typography></MenuItem>
              </Menu>
          <Typography variant="h5" color="inherit" className={classes.text}>
            Text
          </Typography> 

        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

no error messages, the text just dont align

Comment: can you share your working code in any online ide like jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-8tf78?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

Give your heading text 100% width and text-align it to center. Like below.

```
text: {
    width: "100%",
    textAlign: "center"
}
```

This should do the trick.